# Unable to append year in date variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

in below code i am expecting the year should be

2000,2001,2002 upto 2010

But i am getting is 
2005, 2010, 2016 etc

```
var firstDate = new Date(2000, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00, 00);
var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 newDate.setDate(newDate.getFullYear() + i);
 alert(new Date(newDate));
 newDate = new Date(newDate);
}
```

Any idea what the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setYear` instead of `setDate`

Comment: modified bit of code as well and it worked fine. in last line newDate = new Date(firstDate);